# Directories that do not affect class namespace in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, autoload, directory-structure

I am building a Rails 5.2.x application and I am looking for ways to improve the directory structure of my project.

Some model classes in my application represent events and I would like to separate these from other classes which do not represent events.

So ideally I would like to have an `events` subdirectory like this:

```
[RAILS ROOT]/app/models/something.rb
[RAILS ROOT]/app/models/events/some_event.rb
```

Which contain `Something` and `SomeEvent` reprectively.

It seems though, that Rails would require me to name the event class `Events::SomeEvent` in this case.

My actual classes already heavily use namespaces and therefore have long and clumsy names. I would like being able to easily separate my event classes visually while development, without them having even longer names.

Also, in case of the events, I would like to avoid changing the class names, because loading of historical data uses the name for deserialization into the correct class.

Is there a way to introduce additional subdirectories in Rails without the need to represent them as a namespace component? If so, I would really like to know how.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I suspect you can find it in the [Autoloading and Reloading Constants Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Comment: Ruby on Rails uses convention over configuration a lot and is highly opinionated. My advice is: Follow these conventions and do not try to fight them. If you leave the default path it will make your life much harder and you will certainly regret it in the future.

Comment: Rails and its community used this argument since its beginning to excuse its lack of flexibility. But the idea of convention over configuration does not imply that. It just implies that there are sane defaults. Overall Rails has become much better in this regard and it should, because as Rails applications grow, the Rails way doesn't fit and is an impediment to maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of convention over configuration is to make you code in easier and conventional way, despite of that Rails offers you a lot of flexibility to reflect your ideas within your application. In your case, if you want to introduce additional directories to your models just add the **config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/events)** (It was image in my case, the picture deepicts the same)in **config/application.rb** so that you class look like:

[image]

and my classes looks as regular one without any namespaces. This should solve your purpose.